# Async call to Azure Table Storage

Tags: azure, asynchronous, .net-core, azure-table-storage

The following is the method I use to read data from Azure Table Storage (ATS) in my .NET Core class library.

The question is although this method is making an async call to ATS, I can't `await` it. How do I modify this method so that I can make it a "standard" `async` method?

```
public T Get<T>(string partitionKey, string rowKey, string tableName) where T : ITableEntity, new()
{
    var table = GetTable(tableName);

    TableQuery<T> query = new TableQuery<T>().Where(
        TableQuery.CombineFilters(
           TableQuery.GenerateFilterCondition("PartitionKey", QueryComparisons.Equal, partitionKey),
           TableOperators.And,
           TableQuery.GenerateFilterCondition("RowKey", QueryComparisons.Equal, rowKey))).Take(1);

    var result = new T();

    TableContinuationToken continuationToken = null;
    do
    {
       Task<TableQuerySegment<T>> querySegment = table.ExecuteQuerySegmentedAsync(query, continuationToken);
       TableQuerySegment<T> segment = querySegment.Result;
       result = segment.FirstOrDefault();
       continuationToken = segment.ContinuationToken;
     } while (continuationToken != null);

     return result;
}
```

If I simply add `async Task<T>` and the `await` keyword, I get an error where I use `await`.

Comment: Mark your method as async :) So `public async Task<T> GetAsync<T>()`

Comment: You mean without the 'await'

Comment: no, not without the await. That would make it a synchronous method.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> How do I modify this method so that I can make it a "standard" async method?

Replace all calls to `Result` with `await`:

```
Task<TableQuerySegment<T>> querySegment = table.ExecuteQuerySegmentedAsync(query, continuationToken);
TableQuerySegment<T> segment = await querySegment;
```

The compiler will guide you from there.